# Why won't anything upload? - Uploading info blob to Azure with Xamarin

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have been trying for quite some time to get something to upload to my Azure blob container I have set up with an Xamarin.ios project.

I am not sure why it isn't working, and have explored many different options.

I get CS0426 whenever I try and refer to LimaBeans in my Viewcontroller.

Stumped.

This is my View Controller

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UIKit;


namespace storingbuttondataaaa
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        }


        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        partial void FractureBtn_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            //get text box data
            var name = FractureBtn;
            string call = ("call 911, especially if blood is spraying everywhere!");
            string line = string.Format("{0},{1}", name, call); 

            //Store the Information.
            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "HealthJournal.txt");
            File.WriteAllText(filename, line);
            ;
        }

        partial void HandleAddClicked_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {

            activityIndicator.StartAnimating();
            new BlobUpload.LimaBeans();



        }
    }
}
```

and this is my blob upload task:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace storingbuttondataaaa
{
    public class BlobUpload
    {
        public BlobUpload()
        {
        }

        public static async Task LimaBeans(string localPath)
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Task>() != null);
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=itsmypersonalkey");

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("submittedreqforbd");

            // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

            //await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
            await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync("My Head Just Exploaded!");


        }

    }
}
```

What is wrong? I am on the verge of giving up!

Comment: based on this code, you are never calling the LimaBeans() method that actually does the upload.

Comment: Hey @Jason. I forgot to include that when I try and use LimaBeans, "The name LimaBeans does not exist in the type BlobUpload"

Comment: please edit the code to reflect what you are ACTUALLY doing and the actual errors/exceptions that are produced.  Otherwise it's a waste of our time to try and help you debug it.

Comment: @Jason sorry. Fixed

Comment: LimaBeans is a static method, you don't need an instance of BlobUploads to call it.  Just do BlobUploads.LimaBeans();

Comment: @JBuff Can you add the exact error message you are seeing?

Comment: @Jason - So I have done exactly that, and now I am receiving the error "There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter "localPath" of "BlobUpload.LimaBeans(string)"

Comment: YOUR method that YOU wrote includes a parameter localPath.  YOU need to supply that parameter when calling the method.  Or, remove the parameter since you aren't actually using it.

Comment: @Jason Got it. I must have pasted that in there from other threads while I was looking for a solution earlier. Now my button that I am using is throwing "No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method 'ViewController.FractureBtn_TouchUpInside(UIButton)"

Comment: Remove the partial keyword from that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method ViewController.FractureBtn_TouchUpInside(UIButton)

We should define a declaration of this method in another partial class as below:

```
partial void FractureBtn_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender);
```

To upload local file to Azure, we can do as below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Upload file to Blob 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">path of local file. For example: C:\Users\leel2\Desktop\333.txt</param>
    /// <param name="blobName">For example: 333.txt</param>
    /// <param name="containerName"></param>
    public static void UploadBlob(string path, string blobName, string containerName)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=xxxxxxxx");

        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();


        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        blob.UploadFromFile(path);

    }
```